# How to write the test cases that for an restful service that return a list in java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a test case for the service using Junit Mockito.

**Controller class:**

```
public class ReporteesService {
   ReporteeList   reportee   = new ReporteeList();
       GetEmpId       EmpId      = new GetEmpId();
       public ReporteesService(ReporteeList reportee) {
       this.reportee = reportee;
      }
       public ReporteesService(EmpJiraList NumberOfJiras) {
       this.NumberOfJiras = NumberOfJiras;
      }
       public ReporteesService(GetEmpId EmpId) {
       this.EmpId = EmpId;
      }
   @GET
   @Path("/ReporteeList/{empid}")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       public List<Map<Object, Object>> getList(@PathParam("empid")String 
       emp ) throws Exception {
   String id       = EmpId.getEmpId(emp);
       int employeeid  = Integer.parseInt(id);
       return  reportee.getReportees(employeeid);
   }
```

**ReporteeList class:**

```
       public class ReporteeList {
   public List<Map<Object,Object>> getReportees(int idOfEmp) throws 
       Exception {
    Authentication auth = new Authentication();
    JiraCount      count = new JiraCount();
    String api = "https://*******/core/v3/people/";
    int id = idOfEmp;
    String ext = "/@reports";
    String url = api + id + ext;
    String authToken = auth.getToken();
    Client restClient = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(url);
    ClientResponse resp = 
            webResource.accept("application/json").header("Authorization", 
            "Basic " + authToken)
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
    if (resp.getStatus() != 200) {
        System.err.println("Unable to connect to the server");
    }
    String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);

    // JSONParser reads the data from string object and break each 
            data into key
    // value pairs
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    // Type caste the parsed json data in json object
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parse.parse(output);
    // Store the JSON object in JSON array as objects (For level 1 
            array element i.e list)

    JSONArray jsonarr_s = (JSONArray) jobj.get("list");
    List<Map<Object, Object>> List = new 
             ArrayList<Map<Object,Object>>();

    // Get data for List array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_s.size(); i++) {
            Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject) jsonarr_s.get(i);
            JSONObject jive = (JSONObject) jsonobj_1.get("jive");

        Object names = jsonobj_1.get("displayName");
        Object userid = jive.get("username");
        String UserId = userid.toString();


            //return the map with the key value pairs

            int jiracount = count.getJiraCount(UserId);
            map.put("Name", names);
            map.put("UserId", userid);
            map.put("count", jiracount);
            List.add(map);

        }

        return List;
    } 
}
```

**Test class:**

```
       public class ReporteesListTesting {
   ReporteesService Reportee_Service=null;
   ReporteeList Reportee_List = mock(ReporteeList.class);
   GetEmpId     empid         = mock(GetEmpId.class);
   @Before
   public void setup() {
   Reportee_Service = new ReporteesService(empid);

    }
       @Test
   public void testReporteeList() throws Exception {

    when(Reportee_List.getReportees(54591)).thenReturn("");
    assertEquals("",Reportee_Service.getList("vb256121"));

}

 }
```

Now in the Return part I have to return the list, as my `getReportees()` return the list.

The List contains this data:

```
  "[{UserId=at1234,count=0,Name=Amrith Taj}, 
    {UserId=AR1234,count=1,Name=Anaga R}, 
    {UserId=MS1234,count=4,Name=Madhu S}]"
```

Please let me know how can this be done,and whether I am on the right track.Please help,I am new to Junits Mockito.

Comment: what is your actual problem? what do you expect your current code to do? does it do it?

Comment: I am trying to write an test case for the getList() in Controller class using mockito.My doubt is where that function returns the list,so how can I write an test case for that.Please provide any examples to write such test cases.Thanks

Comment: For Controller tests i would suggest to use wiremock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reportee_Service.getList("vb256121") returns a List of Maps, not a string.

```
when(Reportee_List.getReportees(54591)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
assertEquals(0 ,Reportee_Service.getList("vb256121").size());
```

You can do this for a longer query

```
    List<Map<Object, Object>> users = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", "Amrith Taj");
    map.put("UserId", "at1234");
    map.put("count", "0");
    users.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", "Anaga R");
    map.put("UserId", "AR1234");
    map.put("count", "1");
    users.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name", "Anaga R");
    map.put("UserId", "MS1234");
    map.put("count", "4");
    users.add(map);
    when(Reportee_List.getReportees(54591)).thenReturn(users);
    assertEquals(3 ,Reportee_Service.getList("vb256121").size());
```